# Colimits exist in reflective subcategories of co-complete categories.

Tags: category-theory

A reflective subcategory $C$ of $D$ is a full subcategory of $D$ such that for any object $d\in D$, if $d$ is isomorphic to some $c\in C$, then $d\in D$ and furthermore the inclusion $i:C\rightarrow D$ has a left adjoint $r:D \rightarrow C$.

I am trying to show:

> Let $C$ be a reflective subcategory of $D$. I am trying to show that
>   if $D$ is co-complete then so is $C$.

I have come up with a solution, but it does not rely on the above introduced definition, so I am wondering if it is correct.

Let $J:I\rightarrow C$ be a diagram. Then $i\circ J: I \rightarrow D$ is a diagram and since $D$ is co-complete we have that $colim_{I} J$ exists in $D$. But then since we have that $r$ is left adjoint to $i$, it preserves colimits so, $$r(\text{colim} _I  (i\circ J)) \cong \text{colim}_I (r\circ i\circ J)\cong \text{colim}_I (J)$$

since we have that $r\circ i \Rightarrow 1_C$. Hence we have exhibited the colimit as an object of $C$.

Is this a correct proof?

Comment: It's a bit unclear how your argument fails to rely on the definition of reflective subcategory. You're critically using that $r\circ i\to 1_C$ is an isomorphism.

Answer (score 3):

The definition of [reflective subcategory](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/reflective+subcategory) only asks for the inclusion functor to be a right adjoint. So it makes sense that you're only using the assumption that $i$ is a right adjoint.

Your argument seems okay. Maybe for clarity one could say something about the last step: you need to use that $ri$ is naturally **isomorphic** to the identity functor. This follows from the fact that $i$ is fully faithful (see Lemma 4.5.13 of Riehl's book [Category Theory in Context](http://www.math.jhu.edu/~eriehl/context.pdf)).

Comment: What condition implies that $i$ is essentially surjective here? I think you're misreading something.

Comment: Definitely so. Fixed it. Thanks!